# When using early stopping for image classification with graph convolutional networks, which value for minimal improvement and patience is recommended?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, graph-neural-network

I'm using early stopping for avoiding overfitting in a task of image classification with a graph convolutional network.
I'm trying to adopt a patience of 5 and a minimal improvement of 0.001.
Is this setting ok?
What are the recommended values for patience and minimal improvement?

Comment: I think that is very hard to decide for people from the internet. It depends on so much things, like your loss function but also architecture the Gradient descent algorithm you are using and the data and the context of it. To get a rough idea you could track and train and test lost and check when you overfit. Then you can check how often the loss did not improve up to that point. This could be a rough estimate. Generally, in my experience, people start to step away from the use of Early Stopping

Comment: @Janosch Thank you. And what people are doing instead of using early stopping?

Comment: People just use a fixed number of epochs. It is for ones more reproducible. Depending on what kind of learning rate scheduler you it also needs to know for how many epochs you are going to train. And without having the source at hand at the moment, it has been observed recently that at least for many LLMs you can see a period of the loss increasing before finally decreasing again.